# Have the makers of Parallels commented on it being made into a TV series?

Tags: parallels

I've just watched [*Parallels*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3479316/) on Netflix.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallels_(2015_film)), this is a possible pilot foreshadowing a series. [This review](http://observationdeck.io9.com/parallels-a-sci-fi-movie-begging-to-be-a-tv-series-1690130825) even suggested that it's possible Netflix put this out there to 'test the water'.

**So, the question is, is there anything official on this from the makers?**

Comment: You might find this reddit discussion with Christopher Leone  interesting http://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/2z1ch1/i_am_christopher_leone_writerdirector_of/

Comment: They have created a petition but it will need a lot more signatures that it's got https://www.change.org/p/netflix-fox-broadcasting-company-make-parallels-a-tv-series-as-originally-intended/u/10400016

Comment: I think parallels was an awesome movie/pilot! My wife and i watched it together and we both loved it. If Netflix picks it up, I will have to order it again. Other wise not until the next season of hemlock grove.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Update #6 - Back into development limbo. Fox has dropped the show pilot (unmade) and Gaiman no longer attached.

> Ah thanks for remembering Parallels! Fox Network passed on the pilot script unfortunately — still possible it could land at another network but looking less likely. I’m developing a few new projects so hopefully one of those will catch fire. Appreciate you checking in!
>
> – [Christopher Leone (@ChristophrLeone)](https://twitter.com/ChristophrLeone/status/1103439652059410437) on Twitter, 6 Mar 2019

### <s>Update #5 - Finally in development by FOX under "The Building" name.</s>

> PARALLELS is now THE BUILDING and the great [@neilhimself](https://twitter.com/neilhimself) is on board! OH SNAP! http://deadline.com/2016/11/neil-gaiman-angry-films-fox-network-the-building-series-development-1201854827/ via [@deadline](https://twitter.com/Deadline)
>
> – [Christopher Leone (@ChristophrLeone)](https://twitter.com/ChristophrLeone/status/798993826920747009?lang=en-gb) on Twitter, 16 Nov 2016

### Update #4 - Still stuck in limbo, it seems

> Parallels is still alive.
>
> – [Christopher Leone (@ChristophrLeone)](https://twitter.com/ChristophrLeone/status/740569832194641920?lang=en-gb) on Twitter, 8 Jun 2016

### Update #3 - Hope springs eternal in the human breast

The show seems to be stuck in development hell but the discussions over the future of the series are evidently still continuing.

> Trying to make the series happen....
>
> – [Christopher Leone (@ChristophrLeone)](https://twitter.com/ChristophrLeone/status/711571643739410432) on Twitter, 20 Mar 2016

---

### Update #2: Still nothing yet, but a glimmer of hope

> Not concrete yet,
>   hopefully I can announce soon. And thanks, much appreciated!
>
> – [Christopher Leone (@ChristophrLeone)](https://twitter.com/ChristophrLeone/status/681245534942724096) on Twitter, Dec 27 2015

### **Update #1: Not Yet**

There may have been some recent progress in their talks with FOXTV

> YOU DIDN'T HEAR IT FROM ME but if you'd like to see Parallels become a
>   series, right now would be a good time to make some noise...
>
> – [Christopher Leone (@ChristophrLeone)](https://twitter.com/Jayfive/status/658431607536230400) on Twitter, Oct 11 2015

---

**Nope.** As of May 2015 there have been no official announcements regarding whether Netflix (or any other Network) will pick up Parallels as a series.

The show's creator; Christopher Leone seems hopeful (see below) but as of 1st May [this podcast](http://www.atomicgeekdom.com/podcasts/2015/4/27/55-christopher-leone) - (<sub><sup>timestamp 48:33</sup></sub>) would indicate that it hasn't happened yet.

> We are hellbent on making more PARALLELS! We're figuring out the next steps now but I should have news to share very soon.
>
> *– Christopher Leone (@ChristophrLeone) [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/christophrleone), 18 Mar 2015*

And more recently

> [@andrewcburnham](https://twitter.com/andrewcburnham) [@Seeversjm](https://twitter.com/Seeversjm) Don't know when, but it's already July -- probably looking at 2016.— Christopher Leone (@ChristophrLeone) [July 10, 2015](https://twitter.com/ChristophrLeone/status/619567722091839488)

Comment: For those who insist on trying to edit out the strikes, please be aware that these are **intentionally stylistic and intended to show progress**.

Comment: I didn’t try to edit them out, but doesn’t your descending update structure already do that quite well?

Comment: @Adamant - Since it's become clear to me that this series is never getting made, the strikes are intended to indicate a sort of relentless "*pointless hope*" motif, with each successive update being crossed off, then replaced with another another of equally low value.

Comment: @Adamant - Well shut my mouth. It looks like this doesn't want to die.

Comment: @Adamant - Aaaaaaand dead.

Comment: As of September 2023, Leone's twitter account is dead. No more updates